# Windows Batch - run a python-script with unknown name

Tags: python, regex, windows, batch-file

I want to be able to run a python-script from a batchfile with not knowing the name of the python-script.

My situation: I have a folder with some files, one batch-script and one python-script. Now i want the batch script to run the python-script in this folder. Sometimes I have a other python-script in this folder. So i cant tell the name of the python-script, which I want to be executed.

Is it possible to do some kind of regular expression in the batch file?
for example:

```
@echo off

::change to folders directory
cd %~dp0    

::run the python script (the file with .py extension)
python .*.py    
pause
```

Comment: Besides doing this in a batch file (which is probably very cumbersome), you could also do it in Python. Make a Python "runner" script that will list the contents of a given directory, look for any ".py" files in it and use "execfile" or "import" to run it. However, you need some kind of rule to distinguish which script should be run.

Comment: Is it the only python file in the current directory?

Comment: the problem is that i need the pausecommand, otherwise the scripts dont work probertly. yes thats the only python script in the directory

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (*.py) do (
  python "%%~fa"
)
```

this will run all python scripts in the folder.If you want to be more specific you can set more detailed mask over the file names (e.g. `script*.py`)

Comment: GREAT! Exactly what I nead. Thank you.